# How do you unlock all of the characters in SSB4?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Here is a list of all the unlockable characters in super smash brothers for the 3DS. How do you unlock them all? Do you have to beat the game a certain number of times like the other super smash games?

Unlockable Characters:

- Ness
- Falco
- Wario
- Lucina
- Dark Pit
- Dr. Mario
- R.O.B.
- Ganondorf
- Mr. Game & Watch
- Bowser Jr.
- Duck Hunt
- Jigglypuff

Comment: For those of you voting to close as unreleased, the game is officially released in Japan as of 13 September 2014.

Comment: @UnionHawk, even so, I think it's a bit early to be asking this. (Not a close vote however)

Comment: @Ben How is it too early? The game is out. Sure it might be a bit until someone comes along with an answer, but the game is released.

Comment: @Unionhawk That's all I mean. It's probably just going to take a while for an answer.

Comment: @Ben How can it take a while? There are already a ton of US players, including myself, that have Japanese consoles with it already installed.

Comment: @memescientist I completely agree. I know a lot of people who are already playing in the US. When I watch them play, they have all of the characters already, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Character unlocks differs between the 3DS and Wii U versions. I'm posting a complete list for both versions below. [Source](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/super-smash-bros-wii-u-3ds/Unlockables)

### Ness

**3DS**: 10 Smash matches or beat Classic mode
**Wii U**: Unlocked by default

### Falco

**3DS**: 20 Smash matches or beat Classic mode  without using any continues
**Wii U**: 10 Smash matches or beat Classic mode

### Wario

**3DS**: 30 Smash matches or complete 100 man smash
**Wii U**: 20 Smash matches or complete 100 man smash

### Lucina

**3DS**: 40 Smash matches or beat classic mode as Marth without using any continues
**Wii U**: 30 Smash matches or beat Master Core (classic mode final boss at intensity 5.1 or greater) as Marth at 5.5 intensity

### Dark Pit

**3DS**: 50 Smash matches   or beat Classic mode with three or more characters
**Wii U**: 40 Smash matches or beat All-Star mode on Normal

### Dr Mario

**3DS**: 60 Smash matches or beat Classic mode as mario at intensity 4.0 or greater
**Wii U**:  50 Smash matches or beat one Master Order on hard difficulty

### R.O.B.

**3DS**: 70 Smash matches or collect 200 trophies then play a Smash match or beat classic mode
**Wii U**: 60 Smash matches or defeat Crazy Hand after completing 10 matches in Crazy Orders

### Ganondorf

**3DS**: 80 Smash matches or beat Classic mode as Link at intensity 5.0 or higher
**Wii U**:  Unlocked by default

### Mr.Game & Watch

**3DS**: 90 Smash matches or beat Classic mode with ten fighters
**Wii U**:  80 Smash matches or beat Classic mode with five fighters

### Bowser Jr

**3DS**: 100 Smash matches or beat Classic Mode as Bowser on Intensity 6.0 or higher
**Wii U**:  Unlocked by default

### Duck Hunt

**3DS**: 110 Smash matches or beat Classic Mode with 8 or more characters
**Wii U**:  100 Smash matches or KO one fighter in Cruel Smash

### Jigglypuff

**3DS**: 120 Smash matches or collect 30 different equipment items
**Wii U**:  Unlocked by default

## DLC Characters

### Mewtwo

**3DS**: $3.99
**Wii U**: $3.99
**Both**: $4.99

### Lucas

**3DS**: $3.99
**Wii U**: $3.99
**Both**: $4.99

### Roy

**3DS**: $3.99
**Wii U**: $3.99
**Both**: $4.99

### Ryu W/ Suzaku Castle

**3DS**: $5.99
**Wii U**: $5.99
**Both**: $6.99
(Note: This DLC comes with the stage as well as the fighter)

### Cloud W/ Midgar

**3DS**: $5.99
**Wii U**: $5.99
 
**Both**: $6.99
(Note: This DLC comes with the stage as well as the fighter)

### Corrin

**3DS**: $4.99
**Wii U**: $4.99
 
**Both**: $5.99

### Bayonetta W/ Umbra Clock Tower

**3DS**: $5.99
**Wii U**: $5.99
**Both**: $6.99
 
(Note: This DLC comes with the stage as well as the fighter)

Answer (score 5):

> - **Ness**: play 10 vs matches or beat classic with 2 characters.
> - **Falco**: play 20 vs matches or beat classic with 1 character.
> - **Wario**: play 30 vs matches or beat 100 man brawl.
> - **Lucina**: play 40 vs matches or beat classic with 3 fire emblem characters.
> - **Dark Pit**: play 50 vs matches or beat classic with 4 characters.
> - **Dr.Mario**: play 60 vs matches or beat classic with Mario.
> - **R.O.B**.: play 70 vs matches.
> - **Ganondorf**: Play 80 vs matches or beat classic with Link.
> - **Mr. Game&watch**: play 90 vs matches or beat classic with Pac Man.
> - **Bowser Jr.**: play 100 vs matches or beat classic with Bowser on 7.0 or higher.
> - **Duckhunt Dog**: play 110 vs matches or beat classic with 8 characters.
> - **Jigglypuff**: play 120 vs matches or beat classic mode with Charizard on 7.0 or higher.

The other characters not mentioned here are unlocked at the start.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/2hs80b/how_to_unlock_all_hidden_characters/)

Comment: This is slightly different from the criterion listed [here](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Unlockable_character#Characters_4).  Which is correct?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft From my experience trying to unlock characters the criteria from your link is correct where there are differences.

Comment: I just unlocked Jigglypuff for completing 50 vs matches, so these criteria and the ones BlueRaja listed are both partially wrong.