# How do I unlock all the characters/stages in Super Smash Bros. 64?

Tags: super-smash-bros

What are the unlock conditions for all the characters & stages in the original Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 64?

Comment: Self answering questions has a bit of a contentious following here. Sometimes, they'll be upvoted, sometimes down. I think game age has a lot to do with it; games that have been out for years has a lot of reference material already out there, while new ones need all the reference you can get.

Comment: For those wondering, I asked this question so it could be used to consolidate similar questions like "[I can't unlock Captain Falcon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/285191/181240)", or "[How do I unlock Pichu and Mewtwo in Super Smash Bros. Melee?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254028/181240)"

Comment: But [tag:super-smash-bros-melee] is a different game

Comment: @Frank Your comment makes a very good point. I think it [deserves further discussion on meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12473/181240).

Comment: *'Question consolidation'* is not a good reason for asking/self-answering a question, unless under very specific circumstances. Self-answered questions are fine, but they should be about problems you've *actually faced* (and overcome) yourself - don't seed questions as a means to duplicate other ones to it.

Comment: I don't quite understand why after it's been brought up so many times, you still feel this need to consolidate so many questions and try to make mass guides that would allow you to mark old questions as duplicates. That's not the point of the site. It is *not* a wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Jigglypuff

- Complete ***1P Game*** (*Classic Mode*)

#### Captain Falcon

- Complete ***1P Game*** (*Classic Mode*) in under 18 minutes

#### Luigi

- Complete ***Break the Targets*** with all 8 starting characters

#### Ness

- Complete ***1P Game*** (*Classic Mode*) with 3 lives on normal or harder difficulty without using continues

#### Mushroom Kingdom (Stage)

- Complete ***1P Game*** (*Classic Mode*) with all 8 original characters

[image: Mushroom Kingdom]

#### Sound Test (Mode)

- Complete ***Break the Targets*** and ***Board the Platforms*** with all characters

[image: Sound Test]

#### Item Switch (Mode)

- Play 100 rounds of Multiplayer

[image: Item Switch mode]

Source: [Smash Wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_unlockables_(SSB))

See also:

- [How do you unlock all of the characters in SSB4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184404/how-do-you-unlock-all-of-the-characters-in-ssb4/192522#192522)
- [How do I unlock all of the stages in Smash Bros for Wii U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-do-i-unlock-all-of-the-stages-in-smash-bros-for-wii-u)

Comment: It's _probably_ worth mentioning that you also need to defeat the character in a 1v1 after you beat the giant hand. I thought Captain Falcon was under 20 minutes? Anyway +1 purely for nostalgia cause I forgot about the Item Switch and Mushroom Kingdom level!